# How does the "=>" operator work in scala in this case?

Tags: scala

I am currently doing an assignment for a course I try to complete.

In the assignment something like this is defined:

```
type Spec = Term=> Term
```

In this case a "Term" is a block of program code.

Now I understand this means I have a Spec in which a Term implies another Term, or resolves to it. Sorry for my bad wording here, english is not my first language.

```
def svc(ctxt: Env)(pre: Spec, s: Stmt): List[Term] = s match {
  case CompStmt(stmts: List[Stmt]) => stmts match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case x::xs => svc(ctxt)(pre, x) ++ svc(ctxt)(asp(ctxt)(pre, x), CompStmt(xs))
  }
  case CondStmt(cond: Expr, ifBranch: Stmt, elseBranch: Stmt) => 
    svc(ctxt)({st: Term=> And(Logic.sem(ctxt, st, cond), pre(st))}, ifBranch) ++
    svc(ctxt)({st: Term=> And(Not(Logic.sem(ctxt, st, cond)), pre(st))}, elseBranch)
  case AssignStmt(lhs: Expr, rhs: Expr) => ??? 
  case SpecStmt(sp) => List(Implies(Logic.sem(ctxt, pre, sp), pre))
}
```

I am wondering about the last case, the "SpecStmt". The method "Logic.sem" is defined as follows:

```
def sem(ctxt: Env, s: Term, e: Expr): Term
```

So I have a `pre` of type `Spec`, e.g. `Term => Term`. I know want to get from the `pre` to a single `Term` which I can pass to the `Logic.sem`-method.

I know I am missing a basic concept here, so can please someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Term => Term` is just a function. To get a `Term`, apply it like `pre(t)` where `t` is a `Term`.

Comment: But I need to extract the `Term` from `pre`...

Comment: As som-snytt has indicated, if you have a `Term => Term`, the only way to get a `Term` out of it is to feed a `Term` in to it.  There is no other option.

Comment: But there is no term I could use. This is the only parameter available... I am all out of ideas, will get 0 points on the assignment.